# Linq: Get a list of all tables within DataContext

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-3.5, datacontext

I have a DataContext (Linq to Sql) with over 100 tables, is it possible to get a list of all those tables and lets say print them to the console? This might be a silly question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's much easier than above and no reflection required. Linq to SQL has a Mapping property that you can use to get an enumeration of all the tables.

```
context.Mapping.GetTables();
```

Comment: actually, this also gives you views

Comment: This seems to not give you "System.Data.Linq.Table"s but "System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable"s

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via reflection. Essentially, you iterate over the properties in your [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) class. For each property, check to see if that property's generic parameter type has the [TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx) attribute. If so, that property represents a table:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data.Linq.Mappings;

PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MyDataContext).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if(property.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    {
        object[] attribs = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false);
        if(attribs.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fast, but a bit over-complex when the Mapping property is right there in Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 4):

```
dc= new myDataContext();
var listaTablas = (from tables in dc.Mapping.GetTables() select tables.TableName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

for SP

```
foreach (var sp in Mapping.ContextType.GetMembers().Where(w=> w.Name.ToLower().Contains("push")).GroupBy(g=>g.Name).Select(s=>s.First()))
{
    sp.Name.Dump();
    sp.ToString().Replace("LINQPad.Return", "").Replace("System.Data.Linq.", "").Dump();
}
```

for Tables

```
foreach (var table in Mapping.GetTables().Where(t => t.TableName.ToLower().Contains("push")))
{
    table.TableName.Dump();
}
```